# Elastic Search "and" operator with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using  elastic  search 2.2 version and using the following query DSL:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product": {
        "query": "Razor 2004",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the following query will be able to pickup all the product which has Razor and 2004 in it .
So for example the following search string result would be valid:

```
"I am using Razor built in  2004"
"Razor 2004 is great"
```

but the following search string result would be invalid

```
"I am using Razor built in  2005"
"Razor is great"
```

The query works well for one search input but how can i modify the query for multiple values like

```
{
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "product": {
            "query": "Razor 2004","Shave 2015"
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now i am looking for strings where either "Razor" and "2004" is present or Shave "and" 2015 in a string.
I tried the  bool query but could not get the "and" like search to work.My bool  query looks like this :

```
{
          "query": {
              "query": {
                  "bool": {
                      "should": [
                          {
                              "match": {
                                  "product": "Razor 2004"
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "match": {
                                  "product": "Shave 2015"
                              }
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Is there any way to provide a "and" like search in a string with multiple IN Values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to specify the combine operator in the match queries to be AND. The default of the match query is OR.

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "product": {
              "query": "Razor 2004",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "product": {
              "query": "Shave 2015",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```